# How to remove the last separator in toString()

Tags: java, tostring

I am combining two matrices:

matrixA =

719.0   501.0   -75.0
    501.0   508.0   -62.0
    -75.0   -62.0   10.0

matrixB =

-19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0
    -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0
    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

matrixA#matrixB- 
combines using `#` and

the row is separated using `,` and

element separated using `|`

My toString code is:

```
public String toString() {
        String separator = "|";
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

        for (int k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
                 for(int l = 0; l < keys[k].length; l++){
                result.append(keys[k][l]);
                result.append(separator);
            }
           result.setLength(result.length() - separator.length());
            // add a line break.
            result.append(",");
        }
       result.append("#");
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++){
                result.append(values[i][j]);
                result.append(separator);
            }
            // remove  separator
            result.setLength(result.length() - separator.length());
            // add a line break.
            result.append(",");
        }
      return result.toString();
    }
```

and my result is:

719.0|501.0|-75.0,501.0|508.0|-62.0,-75.0|-62.0|10.0`,`#-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0,-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0,0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0`,`

How to remove the last separator?

Comment: if(i!=(values.length)-1) {result.append(",");}

Comment: This is a typical use case where you should prefer `StringBuilder` to `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding separator to the end of the entity(row, element etc.), you can add it to the beginning of the next entity.

For example, for `,` you can do this:-

```
for (int k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {

    // add a line break.
    if (k != 0)
        result.append(",");

    for(int l = 0; l < keys[k].length; l++){
        result.append(keys[k][l]);
        result.append(separator);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply remove it by getting a substring without the last element.

```
return result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
```

Comment: +1, but the `toString` is redundant. [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#substring(int)) can be used directly on `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - You'd have edited the answer. I didn't realize that actually. Anyways, edited it now! Thanks:)

Comment: Downvoters, care to comment?! I don't mind your downvotes, but can you give out your pointers so that I could improve this post?

Comment: And if it is not the last operation on `StringBuffer`, `result.setLength(result.length()-1);` may be used before proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

```
result.toString().replaceAll(",$", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to add a if condition to check the value of i/k and add a (,) based on it.