# Parse a string to two Two Dimensional String Array

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

This question is a continuation from [How to remove the last separator in toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783726/how-to-remove-the-last-separator-in-tostring?noredirect=1#19783744).

My string which is needed to be parsed is:

```
719.0|501.0|-75.0,501.0|508.0|-62.0,-75.0|-62.0|10.0#-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0,-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0,0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0
```

How to get them in 2 string arrays?

```
String [][] key = 719.0 501.0   -75.0   
                  501.0 508.0   -62.0   
                  -75.0 -62.0   10.0

String [][] value = -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   -19.0   
                    -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   -20.0   
                     0.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

The thing is, I may not be knowing the no of rows and column. But for sure there will be only 2 such matrices.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the last separator in toString()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783726/how-to-remove-the-last-separator-in-tostring)

Comment: If you don't know the sizes you need to either 1) parse the `String` and work them out or 2) use a `List`.

Comment: First you check the input format and you count rows and columns. Second, you create yours arrays. Third you fill them.

Comment: why my question gets downvote? And it is the continuation of the other which i hav posted and it is nt a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about splitting the string at the '#' and parsing the two result string separately?

Comment: Yes , i also thought of that. let me chck out

Answer (score 1):

Try that. But here I assume that your rows have the same number elements. So it's not possible to have one row with 5 columns and another with 3.

```
public class StringToArraySandBox {

        protected void doShow(String text) {

            for (String array : text.split("#")) {
                String[][] array1 = doParsing(array);

                for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < array1[i].length; y++) {
                        System.out.print(array1[i][y]);
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }

            }
        }

        protected String[][] doParsing(String text) {

            String[][] result = null;

            String[] rows = text.split(",");
            int rowIndex = 0;
            for (String row : rows) {
                String[] columns = row.split("\\|");

                if (result == null)
                    result = new String[rows.length][columns.length];

                int columnIndex = 0;
                for (String column : columns) {
                    result[rowIndex][columnIndex] = column;

                    columnIndex++;
                }

                rowIndex++;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String target = "719.0|501.0|-75.0,501.0|508.0|-62.0,-75.0|-62.0|10.0#-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0|-19.0,-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0|-20.0,0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0";
            new StringToArraySandBox().doShow(target);
        }

    }
```